# DBT: same code serving for dev/stage/prod environments

Tags: informatica, dbt

I am trying to set up DBT with same code serving for our dev/stage/prod environments, our dev database is like EDW_TEL_ETL_DB_DV1/EDW_TEL_ETL_DB_DV3 and stage/qa database is like EDW_TEL_ETL_DB_TS1/EDW_TEL_ETL_DB_TS3 and production is as EDW_TEL_ETL_DB to achieve this i have the sources.yml as below:

```
sources:
  - name: EDW_TEL_ETL_DB_SS 
    database:  |
      {%- if   target.name == "dev1" -%}   EDW_TEL_ETL_DB{{ env_var("DBT_DATABASE_LIFECYCLE_SUFFIX_1","") }}
      {%- elif target.name == "dev2" -%}   EDW_TEL_ETL_DB{{ env_var("DBT_DATABASE_LIFECYCLE_SUFFIX_3","") }}
      {%- elif target.name == "qa1"  -%}   EDW_TEL_ETL_DB{{ env_var("DBT_DATABASE_LIFECYCLE_SUFFIX_1","") }}
      {%- elif target.name == "qa3"  -%}   EDW_TEL_ETL_DB{{ env_var("DBT_DATABASE_LIFECYCLE_SUFFIX_3","") }}
      {%- elif target.name == "prod" -%}   EDW_TEL_ETL_DB
      {%- else -%} invalid_database
      {%- endif -%}
    schema: SS
    tables:
    - name: ACCOUNTS_USAGE
```

and in the profiles.yml as:

```
snowflake-profile:
  target: dev1
  outputs:
    dev1:
      type: snowflake
```

sample sql:

```
FROM {{source('EDW_TEL_ETL_DB_SS', 'ACCOUNTS_USAGE') }}
```

However after compiling the model database resolves as "invalid_database" rather than EDW_TEL_ETL_DB_DV1
I tried passing "dev1" as args while calling dbt run and created a job and set the target name as "dev1" both did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by updating "Target Name" under "Development Credentials" section, Profile > Credentials > Select the project > Development Credentials> Edit> update the "Target Name"